# Is it possible to declare return type for closure?

Tags: scala, closures

I'm learning closure in scala programming language.

For example:

```
val a = (x:Int, y:Int) => x + y;
a(1, 2)
```

will give me `3`. the closure `a` works like a function `(Int, Int):Int`.

Is it possible to declare the return type for closure like this ?

```
val a = (x:Int, y:Int):Int => x + y;
a(1, 2)
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is impossible (`val a = (x:Int, y:Int):Int => x + y`), but you can declare type for `a`:

`val a: (Int, Int) => Int = (x, y) => x + y`

Comment: One more question, can I write statements in a block with semicolon in closure like this: `val g:(Int,Int)=>Int = (a:Int, b:Int) => { return a + b; }` ?

Comment: it's a legal expression but only without `return` keyword

Comment: *This syntax is impossible...* Actually one can write `val a = (x: Int, y: Int) => (x + y): Int` with type ascription.